# Parse failure using Boost datetime library with time zone string

Tags: c++, parsing, exception, datetime, boost

I'm trying to parse a date/time string in a custom format using Boost's date time library.  The format I'm trying to use is rather unusual because it includes the Posix time zone description string.  The [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/date_time.html) for the library [clearly state](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.format_flags) that there is a flag (`%ZP`) usable for both input and output that handles the Posix time zone string.  The value I'm trying to parse is coming from a web browser, and rather than write JS to perform the transformation specified in the zone string and then send to the server in UTC, I'd rather just do it server-side (since Boost should do this really easily).  Obviously I wouldn't be posting here if it worked.  This code throws a `boost::bad_lexical_cast` with a value of "source type value could not be interpreted as target".

```
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost::local_time;
using namespace boost::gregorian;

std::istringstream ss("1989-11-09T15:30:42.005;PST-8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0");
ss.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit);
local_time_input_facet* facet = new local_time_input_facet("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%F;%ZP");
ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), facet));

local_date_time ldt(not_a_date_time);

ss >> ldt; // do the parse

std::cout << ldt.to_string();
```

However, if you replace the format string with `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%F;"`, the parse succeeds just fine (of course it outputs a value in the wrong time zone).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  The docs for the `%ZP` flag don't have an example, so I'm not sure how it's supposed to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your format string should look like this: `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%s *;%ZP` the `%s *` will match seconds and fractional seconds. With this change, the above code runs, bizarely though, the output I get is:

`1989-Nov-09 15:30:42.005000 ST`

Not sure why it says `ST` rather than `PST`, however the timezone information does get parsed correctly, if you change the date for example to Nov-01, then it will report `PDT`.

EDIT: the description of the time zone object is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html#date_time.local_time.posix_time_zone).

---

Okay, from messing around with this, it appears that the parsing error is caused by the presence of the `;`, removing it from the original string such that it becomes:

```
std::istringstream ss("1989-10-16T15:30:42.005 PST-8PDT,M3.2.0,M10.2.0");
```

And changing the format string to:

```
local_time_input_facet* facet = new local_time_input_facet("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s %ZP");
```

correctly reports:

```
1989-Oct-16 15:30:42.005000 PST
```

If you change the input string again to:

```
std::istringstream ss("1989-10-16T15:30:42.005 PST-8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0");
```

the output is again correct:

```
1989-Oct-16 15:30:42.005000 PDT
```

This tells me that is is indeed honouring the timezone information embedded in the string... so the interesting question is why is it barfing if there is a `;`?

Further update, it appears that the input string can only contain alphanumerics, characters from the set `.:-,` and spaces - after the fractional bits - i.e. you cannot separate the timezone information stuff with any character other than what I've listed above (it's not exhaustive, don't have the time to test for all of them!)

Comment: I was very excited when I read your answer, but I've tried it and it doesn't work for me.  I also tried using only `%s` instead of `%s *` with the same results.  I believe you are misinterpreting the docs regarding `%s *`; the asterisk indicates a footnote that says it is behavior unique to Boost (since most of these format specifiers are the same as `strftime()`).  What version of Boost are you using?  I'm using 1.40.0.

Comment: Sorry about that, I think it was 2am when I looked at this. I've only got 1.4.5 to test with, see the update...

Comment: this is fascinating... I've worked around the issue in another way already, but I'll accept your answer even though I haven't verified it myself.  Too bad the docs don't mention the restrictions on characters!  Thanks.